# Vary variables from behaviorSpace when there is already a procedure in the model to record results

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to use behaviorSpace in order to run 99 simulations. In my netlogo interface, I defined a slider "ID-simulation" (from 1 to 99) and I created a code which allows to save locations X, Y of each turtle and "ID-simulation" in a file .txt. As I have already a procedure in my model to record results, I don't need to record results for each run from "Measure runs at every step" option in behaviorSpace (by using Table Spreadsheet formats). So, How can I vary "ID-simulation" in my file. txt from behaviorSpace ?

Should I define:

```
["ID-simulation" [1 1 99]]
```

in "Vary variables as follows" in behaviorSpace and run 1 repetition instead of running 99 repetitions from behaviorSpace ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, I'm running 1 repetition but I don't understand why I have 8 created files .txt. However, in the windows "Running experiment", it's indicated : "run #1 of 100, step #0". I should have 1 file .txt instead of 8 files. Before to use behaviorSpace, the recording of results was correct.

Comment: Does it work if you set "Simultaneous runs in parallel" to 1 when you run the experiment? (And was it 8 before, is that where the 8 is coming from?) Maybe the problem is that you're trying to write to the same file from 8 parallel threads; I wouldn't expect that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks right. Also, when you run the experiment, you can uncheck both output types to prevent it from doing its normal data recording.